# how to get a div from a url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app running locally and I will like to get a particular div from this url using jquery without loading the complete page. There is a section which contains a button for opening a modal dialog. I went through some few examples I found here but could not solve my problem. below is the page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("https://localhost:44330/",{},function(response){
            $(response).find('testblock').each(function(){
                $('#main').append($(this).html());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Hello from sub application 2</h1>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content" style="height: 90%; width: 100%">
                <div class="modal-body" id="main">
                    @*<iframe src="https://localhost:44330/" width="1200" height="700" style="overflow: hidden; height: 90%; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;" scrolling="yes"></iframe>*@

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/modalClick.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the url has the following structure

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="testblock">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">Open modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal5" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="height: 100%">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content" style="height: 90%">
                <div class="modal-body" style="height: 90%">

            </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="myBtn5">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried [this](http://blog.luutaa.com/how-to-get-specific-div-from-ajax-response/) example but doesn't work

Comment: Firstly you missed the "."  it should "$(response).find('.testblock').each" also see what is the result of "response" in call back.

Comment: i just made the change as you suggested but still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use # in front of testblock .find('#testblock') since it's by ID.  The . would be use if you're trying to locate something by class name.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but even after replacing that with #, i still can't see the modals

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `#`. You defined *testblock* as ID. `<div id="testblock"> ...`

```
$(response).find('#testblock') ...
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work. my idea was to put the entire div content in a modal containing an IFrame. but the page is still blank

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this after going through the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) with a slight adjustment.

```
<script>
    function ready() {
        $("#main").load("https://localhost:44330/ #testblock",
            function (response)
            {
                });
            }
        $(document).ready(ready);
</script>
```